# Why Struts 2 doesn't provide easier method for retrieving request parameters?

Tags: java, servlets, struts2

I rewrite application from servlets to Struts 2.

Previously to get parameter value I could write:

```
request.getParameter("name");
```

Now I should do:

```
public class MyAction implements ParameterAware {
  private Map<String, String[]> parameters;

  @Override
  public void setParameters(Map<String, String[]> parameters) {
    this.parameters = parameters;
  }

  public String getParameterValue(String name){
    return parameters.get(name)[0];
  }

  // get this parameter
```

It was much easier when I used servlets!

To make code DRYer I can create class CustomActionSupport extending ActionSupport and put this code there. But why Struts doesn't do it for me? How can I make my life easier?

<sub>I use ParameterAware as documentation [says that it's a preferred way](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/how-can-we-access-request-parameters-passed-into-an-action.html).</sub>

Comment: For what reason would you need access to the parameter map?

Comment: @Quaternion I want to get request parameter in execute method

Comment: why not just make a setter by name for it? Say the parameter is called Qwerty, you could just put a 'public String qwerty = "default";' in your action and then, if a parameter was passed into the action called "qwerty" with a value of "xyz", the querty parameter would now contain "xyz". You can't get much more straight forward, it will also account for the built in types and enums.

Comment: @Quaternion Could you write an answer about it? I'd want to accept it

Comment: There already *is* an answer that says that.

Comment: @Quaternion I know about getter/setter generation. The original issue (because of which I asked question) was that I was new to Struts and haven't known about ParameterInterceptor at all. Last edit of erickson's answer shows how to use it.

Comment: Sorry I'll delete that, should have read your profile. Questions answered shows you are certainly not new to Java. Well... Other facts, you should be able to use public properties without setters, also some developers are using groovy for the action classes I tried this to prove that it was easy (getters/setters are not typical of groovy for some reason) but I still use Java as I'm more comfortable with the syntax and don't need the dynamic functionality yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal use case for Struts2 is to have action properties that correspond to parameters, and let the [parameters interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html) set these for you before the action is executed.

Struts2 is trying to hide the fact that your action is invoked as the result of an HTTP request. Trying to work directly with parameters is fighting that paradigm.

---

[Here's a small example](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4.1/docs/coding-struts-2-actions.html) relying on the parameters interceptor. First, define a value object.

```
public class Name {

  private String firstName;
  private String surname;

  public void setFirstName(String s) {
    this.firstName = s;
  }

  public void setSurname(String s) {
    this.surname = s;
  }

  /* Some interesting operations on Name... */

}
```

Define your Struts2 action to use `Name`. The properties of name will be set with HTTP parameters before `execute()` is called.

```
public class NameAction extends Action {

  private final Name name = new Name();

  public Name getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public String execute() {
    /* Use "name" to do something interesting; its properties are set. */
  }

}
```

Now create a form that uses your action:

```
<s:form action="name">
  <s:textfield name="name.firstName" label="First name" />
  <s:textfield name="name.surname" label="Last name" />
  <s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

Now the parameters will be set on your `Name` object when the form is submitted to the `NameAction`.

You can set up the framework to do a lot more, such as validating parameters, using a IoC container to inject your action with objects, etc.